# XSLT key element: "use" parent node of the "match"

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I can't seem to figure this thing out. Is it at all possible to have the following key?

```
<xsl:key name="kMatchSentenceID_withTokId" match="sentences/sentence/@ID"
         use="--and here return the 'sentences' node--"/>
```

I don't get how "use" works, isn't it supposed to be a value that you return when the match was matched?

I see that `use="."` returns the value of the attribute in my case. (Why? Is it linked to the match? Shouldn't `.` mean `node()`? and not `node()/@`)

But most importantly, how come I can't do something like this: `use="parent::sentence[@ID=name()]"`

How would I go about doing this then? I need a match on the @ID, but to return it's parent (more specifically, the parent's ID).

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be the reference value _to assign_ to the matched nodes?

Comment: @empo: Yes, I saw that after some googling for examples. But that fact shouldn't change anything regarding my need to assign a value that has something to do to the matched value

Comment: So, you want match `sentence/@id` and for each `sentence` return the id of `sentences`, am I correct?

Comment: @empo: Yes, that's right. ...I really thought there was a link to the `match` value that you can take advantage of in `use`, since `use="."` seems to return whatever value is matched in the `match`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't get how "use" works, isn't it
>   supposed to be a value that you return
>   when the match was matched?

No, `use` does not specify anything to be "*returned*". From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key):

> The use attribute is
>   an expression specifying the values of
>   the key; the expression is evaluated
>   once for each node that matches the
>   pattern.

In a mapping of keys to values `use` specifies the keys -- the values of the key, in the spec's language -- and `match` specifies the values that those keys will map to. In other words, `match` specifies *what* to group and `use` specifies *how* to group them .

Say you wanted to group `sentence` elements by the `@ID` of their parent `sentence`. You could do that like this:

```
<xsl:key name="kMatchSentenceID_withTokId" match="sentences/sentence" 
         use="parent::*/@ID"/>
```

Your expression makes no sense:

```
<xsl:key name="kMatchSentenceID_withTokId" match="sentences/sentence/@ID"
         use="parent::sentence[@ID=name()]"/>
```

...because it's trying to group the `ID` attributes by one of their parent `sentence` elements, which is already a mistake, since attributes don't have parents.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming something like this

```
<sentences id="parent">
  <sentence id="childa"/>
  <sentence id="childb"/>
</sentences>
```

You need:

```
<xsl:key name="sentence" match="sentences" use="sentence/@id"/>
```

Then, for example the XPath`key('sentence','childa')/@id` would return 
`'parent'`.

Comment: You are correct, sir! I had misunderstood how keys work. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to help you since you don't actually say what problem you're trying to solve. But you seem to have some conceptual confusion about keys. Think of them this way: if you want to find the E elements that have the value V for their property P, then you need to define the key as `<xsl:key name="N" match="E" use="P"/>` where P is an XPath expression which, using an E element as its context, determines the value of the property in question; and then you need to call it as `key('N', V)`. The use expression can be any XPath expression you like, and it will be evaluated using the matching E element as its context item.

The examples you've given seem to be legal but not very useful; it's not clear what you were hoping they would do.